# How to create a Python class that inherits set and rejects None?

Tags: python, inheritance, set

I'd like to create a Python class that behaves like a `set`, but does not accept `None` as an element. In addition to intializing it, `set` has three functions for adding elements in it: `update()`, `add()`, and `union()`. *Edit: it has others too, making me think individually overwriting everything is not the way to go.* The way I tried to do this is overwriting these functions, but I'm not sure if that is the best, most elegant and pythonic way to do it. Here is my code so far:

```
class FooSet(set):
    def update(self, others):
        if None in others:
            others.remove(None)
        super().update(others)

    def add(self, elem):
        if elem is None:
            return
        super().add(elem)

    def union(self, others):
        if None in others:
            others.remove(None)
        super().union(others)
```

Another problem with this code is that I cannot create a new instance of `FooSet` with a single element the same way as I can with `set`. And I can create an instance that contains `None`. For example:

```
>>> FooSet([1, 2])
FooSet({1, 2})
>>> FooSet({"a", "b"})
FooSet({'b', 'a'})
>>> FooSet({None, 1})
FooSet({1, None})
>>> FooSet(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Could you help me find the best way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Is `some_set.discard(None)` not enough?

Comment: So if someone tries to update the set with another set that contains `None`, you destructively remove `None` from the *other* set?  Wow.

Comment: @MechanicPig That's an improvement for my functions but it's not enough for my need to just use set and discard None after it. That's basically how it's been done until now but now I really need this class. I'd also like to learn how to do it properly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, you missed a bunch of methods that can modify a set.

Comment: @TomKarzes well I need a set like class that does not allow adding None in it. Please tell me if you have better suggestion, I'm looking for advice here. But thanks for pointing out I missed a bunch of other methods.

Comment: I would favour wrapping the set rather than inheriting from `set` as that would give you full control of the interface (i.e. you would only have to provide methods for what you use). Either way, you have to write a certain amount of boiler-plate to get what you want.

Comment: @nintskari If you want to block the `update` method from adding `None`, you can either (1) add the elements one-by-one, skipping `None` is it's present, or (2) add everything, then remove `None` from the *result*.  What you *can't* do is start changing the passed argument.  That is completely inappropriate for something like this.